# Deployment of CEP Bucket and BAM Hive scripts to multiple nodes

Tags: deployment, wso2, wso2-cep, wso2-bam

Can we store CEP bucket under governance registry and access from multiple other CEP nodes?
Can we store BAM Hive scripts under governance registry and access from multiple other BAM nodes?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Regarding the CEP, AFAIK at the moment there is no any implementation available to store the CEP bucket in governance registry and access from multiple other CEP nodes. Only way is deploy the configuration file (bucket xml) in the file system... but you can store the Text & XML output mapping in registry as shown in [1] and use that in the bucket configuration file.

[1] http://docs.wso2.org/wiki/display/CEP210/Text+Output+Mapping

Comment: Does CEP bucket and BAM hive scripts get stored in Config registry and is there any way to share config registry across various nodes ?

Comment: The answer which I gave is also match for config registry in the CEP point of view. Because at the moment there is no any implementation available to retrieve the whole bucket information from the registry (only supports to retrieve Text & XML output mapping).

Answer (score 2):

In the BAM normally hive scripts are saved in config/repository/hive/scripts. At the moment you can't change to any other registry. If in distributed mode each BAM analyzer node will access to the above location. There is one alternative way if you want to store your script in governance registry. Create a hive script with just a variable like ${gov:/path} and save actual hive script content in that path as a String like shows in [1]. At runtime this variable will replace with that location's content.

[1] - http://docs.wso2.org/wiki/display/BAM230/Populating+Script+Parameters+at+Runtime#PopulatingScriptParametersatRuntime-UsingtheGUItogetvaluesfromtheregistry

Answer (score 2):

If your question is sharing the registry between WSO2 BAM nodes, then of course we can do it. There are multiple ways [1] and if you are having a cluster of BAM analyzer nodes then you need to share the registry among the analyzer nodes[2]

[1] http://wso2.com/library/tutorials/2010/04/sharing-registry-space-across-multiple-product-instances

[2] http://docs.wso2.org/wiki/display/BAM230/Fully-Distributed%2C+High-Availability+BAM+Setup